# JMeter - Why use JDBC PostProecssor over sampler

Tags: jmeter

In JMeter test plan, why do I need JDBC post (/pre)proecssor when I can just use JDBC sampler?

If the relevant sampler will be before/after the request it will be same as JDBC Pre/Post processor

Also it seems more reusable option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default JMeter does not include the time required to execute any [Pre Processors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#preprocessors) into sample result. Same applies to [Post-Processors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and [Timers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers)  (unless you are using [Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) configured to do so)

So I would use Pre Processor if it assumes some pre-requisities setup and I am **not interested** in its results timings.

If I **need to measure** the time required to execute a request - I would go for Sampler

Check out [A Quick Guide to JMeter PreProcessors](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/quick-guide-jmeter-preprocessors) article for comprehensive information on using Pre Processors in JMeter tests.

Comment: Dmitri, I could not find in links you gave info on "By default JMeter does not include the time required to execute ..." (I've searched for `time`). Could you point where it is written in the docs or/and source code?